# finding a word in a string without spaces

Tags: python, regex

I have a string without space. eg `system-gnome-theme-60.0.2-1.el6`. 
I have to check in 100 other such strings (without space) which have a few of the previously specified words; e.g. `gnome`, `samba`.

How do I do it in python?

There can be any prefix or suffix in the string attached with `samba`. I have to detect them, what do I do?

Currently I have done this:

```
for x in array_actual:
    for y in array_config:
        print x.startswith(y)
        print ans
```

which is completely wrong because it is checking only the first word of the string. That word can be anywhere, between any text.

Comment: What is the expected outpute of the mentioned string, as I'm bit confused by this 'question'?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `str.startswith()`, use the `in` operator:

```
if y in x:
```

or use a regular expression with the `|` pipe operator:

```
all_words = re.compile('|'.join([re.escape(line.split(None, 1)[0]) for line in array_config]))

for x in array_actual:
    if all_words.search(x):
```

The `'|'.join([...])` list comprehension first escapes each word (making sure that meta characters are matched literally, and are not interpreted as regular expression patterns). For the list `['gnome', 'samba']` this creates the pattern:

```
gnome|samba
```

matching any string that contains either word.

Comment: the list is in a file. i cannot explicitly state the list..the for loop is reading the words that need to be searched.also if y in x doesnt work atall.

Comment: @user2779092: Then read the words **first** from that file, into a list. Don't forget to strip the newlines and other whitespace. You cannot repeatedly loop over a file object *anyway*, not without re-opening or rewinding the file pointer to the start each time.

Comment: @user2779092: repeatedly reading the file would not be a good idea either, as reading from disk is *slow* compared to just storing it as a list in memory. Not nesting loops like you did, instead using a regex, would be faster again.

Comment: for line in array_config:
        t= line.partition(' ')[0]
        x_config.append(t)


for line in array_actual:
        if line.search(x_config):
                print "FOUND"         I MADE AN ARRAY AND PASSED IT TO THAT line.search..but it will say no object to search.

Comment: @user2779092: `x_config = [line.split(None, 1)[0] for line in array_config]` would do that in one go. `line.search(x_config)` *will not work*, because strings have no `.search()` method. The `.search()` in my answer is a method of the compiled regular expression.

Comment: can u help me out with this section of the code? how would u do it? i have a config file with names of rpm packages that i want to check if they exist. and an actual_config file which has the list of packages... thats what i am doin in the codes above

Comment: hey no m done. got the output...u martin..r amazing. internet is awesome cuz of guys like u *.*